# Disable right click in asp project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have done my project in asp. I want to disable the right click and copy past for whole project. Any idea for that, in project no of users and more than 1 master page.

Comment: It is for one page i want for it my hole project.

Comment: I understand that, but not only is there no other ways to accomplish what you want, what you want is something YOU SHOULDN'T DO.

Answer (score 5):

You can do so with Javascript and/or an HTML attribute

```
    <script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

And....

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</body>
```

Comment: Can u tell me how I use it in external java script. I have number of pages it is around 100-120. Pages

Comment: @Shailendra y must copy this code in external javascript code

Answer (score 0):

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false"> </body>
```

This will disable the right click on the body.

Comment: I have many master pages.

Comment: You need to write it everywhere. One possible easy way might be to use "Find and Replace" function of the text editor. Find the "<body" text and replace it with <body oncontextmenu="return false"